# SSLSocket.getInputStream() hangs when called Java 11

Tags: java, stream, java-11

I am writing a test class for a networking module which establishes a SSL connection used for sending messages. The Junit 4 test class sets up a client side keystore and truststore along with a server side keystore. These variables are used in setting up client side and server side SSLContexts from which I get SSLServerSocket and SSLSocket necessary for setting up a connection through their respective factories.

The SSLServerSocket successfully accepts the connection of my SSLSocket on localhost at the same port. However when I call the SSLSocket.getInputStream() method on the server side socket it hangs whereas calling the SSLSocket.getOutputStream() mehtod on the client side is successful. I am aware that this stage is responsible for initiating the SSL handshake but through my search I have found little on what could be causing a single side to hand. Someone elses post on a separate site mentioned that is could be a reverse dns lookup hanging how would I prevent this? I also tried explicitly starting the handshake in the first of the two Callable threads which hung in a similar fashion. This is my test class:

```
 public class ReceiverClientThreadTest {

// ADD REG AND A SINGLE NETWORK
// ESTABLISH A TLS CONNECTION BETWEEN TWO POINTS WITH
private final static String KEY_MANAGER = "SunX509";
private final static String TLS_VERSION = "TLSv1.2";
private final static String RNG_ALGORITHM = "DEFAULT";
private final static String RNG_PROVIDER = "BC";
private static final String PROVIDER = "BC";
private static final String KEYSTORE_TYPE = "PKCS12";
private static KeyStore keyStore1, keyStore2, trustStore2;
private SSLSocket serverSocket;
private SSLSocket clientSocket;

@BeforeClass
public static void setUp() throws SQLException, GeneralSecurityException, OperatorCreationException, IOException {


    String name1 = "localhost", name2 = "client";
    KeyPair kp1 = SecurityUtilities.generateKeyPair();
    KeyPair kp2 = SecurityUtilities.generateKeyPair();
    X509Certificate cert1 = SecurityUtilities.makeV1Certificate(kp1.getPrivate(), kp1.getPublic(), name1);
    X509Certificate cert2 = SecurityUtilities.makeV1Certificate(kp2.getPrivate(), kp2.getPublic(), name2);

    keyStore1 = KeyStore.getInstance(KEYSTORE_TYPE, PROVIDER);
    keyStore2 = KeyStore.getInstance(KEYSTORE_TYPE, PROVIDER);
    trustStore2 = KeyStore.getInstance(KEYSTORE_TYPE, PROVIDER);


    keyStore1.load(null, null);
    keyStore1.setKeyEntry(name1, kp1.getPrivate(), "relaypass".toCharArray(), new X509Certificate[]{cert1});

//        keyStore2.load(null, null);
//        keyStore2.setKeyEntry(name2, kp2.getPrivate(), null, new X509Certificate[]{cert2});

    trustStore2.load(null, null);
    trustStore2.setCertificateEntry(name2, cert1);

//        secureSocketManager = new SecureSocketManager(keyStore1, password);
}




@Before
public void init() throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException, InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
    SSLServerSocket sslServerSocket = getSSLServerSocket();
    SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = getSSLSocketFactory();
    ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);

    Callable<SSLSocket> c1 = () -> {
        return (SSLSocket) sslServerSocket.accept();
    };

    Callable<SSLSocket> c2 = () -> {
        return (SSLSocket) sslSocketFactory.createSocket("localhost", 2048);
    };

    Future<SSLSocket> server = pool.submit(c1);
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    Future<SSLSocket> client = pool.submit(c2);
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    serverSocket = server.get();
    clientSocket = client.get();
}

@After
public void tearDown(){
    serverSocket = null;
    clientSocket = null;
}

@org.junit.Test
public void endSession(){

        Thread test = new Thread(new ReceiverClientThread(serverSocket));

        test.start();
        try (ObjectOutputStream output = new ObjectOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream()))) {
            System.out.println("here");
        }catch (IOException e){
            fail();
        }

}


private SSLServerSocket getSSLServerSocket() throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
    char[] entryPassword = "relaypass".toCharArray();
        // COULD ADD PROVIDER IN THESE FOR CONSISTENCY
    KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("PKIX", "BCJSSE");
    keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore1, entryPassword);

    // specify TLS version e.g. TLSv1.3
    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance(TLS_VERSION, "BCJSSE");
    sslContext.init(keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers(),null, null);

    SSLServerSocketFactory fact = sslContext.getServerSocketFactory();
    return (SSLServerSocket) fact.createServerSocket(2048 );
}

private SSLSocketFactory getSSLSocketFactory() throws GeneralSecurityException{

    char[] entryPassword = "relaypass".toCharArray();
    // COULD ADD PROVIDER IN THESE FOR CONSISTENCY
//        KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KEY_MANAGER, "BCJSSE");
//        keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore1, entryPassword);

    TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("PKIX", "BCJSSE");
    trustManagerFactory.init(trustStore2);
    // specify TLS version e.g. TLSv1.3
    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance(TLS_VERSION, "BCJSSE");
    sslContext.init(null,trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers(), null);
   return  sslContext.getSocketFactory();
}
```

This is the class which it is testing and the only relevant line, the one where the code hangs is commented as such:

```
 public class ReceiverClientThread implements Runnable {

private final SSLSocket sslSocket;


public ReceiverClientThread(SSLSocket sslSocket) {
    this.sslSocket = sslSocket;

}

public void run() {

        try (ObjectInputStream input = new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(sslSocket.getInputStream()))) {

            System.out.println("here");
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could set a timeout on your sslSocket, so that if it hangs during stream read, it will only hang for a set period of time and then will throw an exception.  This way the thread will not just hang indefinitely.

```
sslSocket.setSoTimeout(120000); // timeout of 2 min
```